# Python How to override a class member in the child and access it from parent?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

So in Python I have one class like this:

```
class Parent(object):
    ID = None

    @staticmethod
    def getId():
        return Parent.ID
```

Then I override the ID in a child class, like this:

```
class Child(Parent):
    ID = "Child Class"
```

Now I want to call the `getId()` method of the child:

```
ch = Child()
print ch.getId()
```

I would like to see "Child Class" now, but instead I get "None".
How can I achive that in Python?

PS: I know I could access `ch.ID` directly, so this may be more a theoretical question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a class method:

```
class Parent(object):
    ID = None

    @classmethod
    def getId(cls):
        return cls.ID

class Child(Parent):
    ID = "Child Class"

print Child.getId() # "Child Class"
```